# How to pass an optional argument from Fortran subroutine to a R wrapper

Tags: r, fortran, wrapper, gfortran

I have a Fortran subroutine which uses an optional argument in the call.

```
subroutine data (n,ns,alpha,covmat,x,y) 

integer, intent(in):: n,ns
double precision, intent(in)  :: alpha
double precision, intent(in), optional ::covmat(n,ns)
double precision, intent(out) :: x(n),y(n)
....
end subroutine data
```

I tried the following R wrapper for this subroutine and got an error message:

```
 Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x), : 
'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

I'm not sure if I passed the arguments correctly in the .Fortran() call. I couldn't find anything helpful online.

```
data1 <- function(n,ns,alpha,covmat=NULL){

tmp <- .Fortran("data",
n = as.integer(n),ns= as.integer(ns)
alpha=as.numeric(alpha),covmat=as.vector(covmat),
x=as.double(rep(0,n)),y=as.double(rep(0,n)))
)
 }
result <- list(x=tmp$x, y=tmp$y)

return(result)
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "it didn't work"? Never use this phrase in questions, it does not mean anything. Did it return some value? Which value? Did it print something? Did it crash? Any error messages?

Comment: @VladimirF: Thanks for the comment. I will keep that in mind for the next post.Got an error message: "Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'".

Comment: You can edit your post to include this information.

Comment: @VladimirF: sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: There is no error message after changing covmat=as.matrix(covmat)to covmat=as.vector(covmat).

The only solution I found so far for my question is to add a flag variable along with the optional argument in .Fortran () call and pass both in the subroutine. The issue now is for 'n' optional arguments, I will have 'nyou will have more flags in this case. Any other suggestions?